# ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-10.04, openldap, ldif

I'm having issues importing users with `ldapadd` and `ldif` files. The error I'm getting is:

```
ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
additional info: structuralObjectClass: no user modification allowed
```

The users imported are all part of `ou=People,dc=example,dc=org`. The LDAP server already contains this base DN.

The `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif` file contains the following ACL entry:

```
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="ou=People,dc=example,dc=org" attrs=children by gr
 oup.exact="cn=Manager,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=org" manage
```

The `ldif` file is imported as follows:

```
ldapadd -f import.ldif -xv -D "cn=drupal,ou=Apps,dc=example,dc=org" -h localhost -W
```

The `cn=drupal,ou=Apps[...]` entry is a member of `cn=Manager,ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=org` so accordingly it should have sufficient permissions to write ([since manage is the highest level of permissions available](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#The%20access%20to%20grant)).

When I issue the `ldapadd` command the import fails on the very first `ldif` entry. The full command output is then:

```
add objectClass:
    top
    person
    inetOrgPerson
add uid:
    John.Merrell
add mail:
    john.merrell@example.org
add cn:
    John D Merrell
add structuralObjectClass:
    inetOrgPerson
add entryUUID:
    65236c42-09b7-1020-9318-9fca7c043dfc
add creatorsName:
    cn=drupal,ou=Apps,dc=bidnetwork,dc=org
add createTimestamp:
    20110503095643Z
add userPassword:
    2678u8yyy
add givenName:
    John D
add sn:
    Merrell
add entryCSN:
    20110629121956.880164Z#000000#000#000000
add modifiersName:
    cn=drupal,ou=Apps,dc=bidnetwork,dc=org
add modifyTimestamp:
    20110629121956Z
adding new entry "mail=john.merrell@example.org,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org"
ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
    additional info: structuralObjectClass: no user modification allowed
```

I've tested importing users that did or did not exist on the LDAP and I get the aforementioned error in either case.

**Can someone explain the origin of the problem and how it may be circumvented?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How did you generate those LDIF files? `structuralObjectClass` is one of the internal values in OpenLDAP and user - even administrator - cannot normally modify those.

Either remove those `structuralObjectClass` lines from your LDIF or import the entries back with `slapadd` (I bet you generated the LDIF files with `slapcat`).

Comment: I did generate my LDIF files with `slapcat`. If there is a better way please advise. Following your advise I had to remove the following fields for the import to work: `structuralObjectClass`, `entryUUID`, `creatorsName`, `createTimestamp`, `entryCSN`, `modifiersName`, `modifyTimestamp`.

Comment: You should use `slapadd` if you need to restore an LDIF file generated with `slapcat`. The `slapadd` man page says:  "The output of slapcat is intended to be used as input to slapadd(8).  The output of slapcat cannot generally be used as input to ldapadd(1) or other LDAP clients with‐
       out  first  editing  the  output.   This  editing would normally include reordering the records into superior first order and removing no-user-modification operational
       attributes."

Comment: Oh - you can generate an `ldapadd` compatible LDIF with `ldapsearch -L [your_other_options] >your_data.ldif`

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'm going to be using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tools like http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page to export the data, don't choose `Include system attributes` in the web UI:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need delete the following lines in the `ldif` file:

```
structuralObjectClass: 
entryUUID: 
creatorsName: 
createTimestamp: 
entryCSN: 
modifiersName: 
modifyTimestamp:
```

Comment: Full answers are preferred here. A 'try this' answer without explanation isn't really useful on a question several years old.

Answer (score 1):

A script is provided here. Usage: `bash SCRIPTNAME a.ldif`. Remember to backup the ldif beforehand.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in structuralObjectClass entryUUID creatorsName createTimestamp entryCSN modifiersName modifyTimestamp contextCSN
do
  sed -i /$i/d $1
done
```

Comment: Seems to be the same as `grep -Ev (structuralObjectClass|entryUUID|creatorsName|createTimestamp|entryCSN|modifiersName|modifyTimestamp|contextCSN)`.

Comment: Yes, better: `grep -Ev "(structuralObjectClass|entryUUID|creatorsName|createTimestamp|entryCSN|modifiersName|modifyTimestamp|contextCSN)" $i > $i.new.ldif`

Answer (score 0):

**Below is not solution to question, but utility code to remove structural elements**.
Sample python code remove structural elements. Use out.ldif

```
structural_elements = ["structuralObjectClass","entryUUID", "creatorsName","createTimestamp","entryCSN", "modifiersName","modifyTimestamp"]
    with open("ldap_data_out.ldif","w+") as outfile:
        with open("ldap_data_in.ldif", "r") as infile:
            lines = infile.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                print line.split(":")[0]
                if line.split(":")[0] in structural_elements:
                    print "ignoring ,", line
                else:
                    outfile.write(line)
```