# ldap_add: Constraint violation (19) additional info: some attributes not unique

Tags: debian, ldap, database, openldap, database-backup

Well I have already gone through [ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)](https://serverfault.com/questions/290264/ldap-add-constraint-violation-19) but couldn't solve my problem!

Problem I'm facing is that, when I'm trying to add users from  `bckup.ldif` file by issuing following command

`ldapadd -x -D "dc=admin,dc=domain,dc=lcl -f bckup.ldif -W`

It's throwing following error

```
adding new entry "uid=doctor.lcl,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=lcl"
ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
    additional info: some attributes not unique
```

I took backup by using `ldapsearch` only not `slapcat`

So my question is What causing the error and How to resolve the error?

Comment: Seems to me that you already have a user id doctor.lcl in your ldap directory, and you cannot create a second user with this samue id due to integrity constraints

Comment: @krisFr: No man. No same entry! I just searched.

Comment: So, check which attribute(s) have to be uniq in your LDAP directory, and then search which attributes are equal between doctor.lcl ones and existing ones. It could be cn, email etc etc...

Comment: @KrisF : Can u tell me how to check which attributes to be unique? I am not so proficient with and some hints will be very helpful.

Comment: You will need to post the LDIF file you're adding from.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one (or more) attribute for `uid=doctor.lcl,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=lcl` contains duplicate value with an already existing LDAP entry, for an attribute defined as unique.

First, check your `slapd.conf` to search for attributes marked as unique.
e.g :

```
# index since the unique overlay will search for matching mail attributes
index mail eq

overlay unique
unique_attributes mail
```

Then perform an ldap search on this (these) unique attribute(s) and find the one which is a duplicate with `uid=doctor.lcl` attributes.